# how to get the Clientid of the div and check if it is visible in Javascript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a div whose ID is changing (dynamically on runtime). How do I find the client ID of the DIV and check if it is visible?

**ASPX Code**

```
<div id="prftdiv" runat="Server" ></div>
```

**Note:** If I use the hard-coded client ID of the div its position changes in the future, the element's ID will change.

Comment: Why is your ID attribute changing? The whole point of an ID or class attribute is so that you can reference them later. Do your IDs share a common substring?

Comment: `$("div[id$='prftdiv']").is(":visible");`

Comment: Where the client id will be written ?

Comment: might as well ask 'how to guess a randomly generated number'. is  it possible to get a selector to that div that does not include its id  ?

Comment: @Mikey DIV CLIENT is is changing when i open the page from chrome to mozila

Comment: Still don't get it. How about is your DIV always stored in the **exact** same location in the markup? If so, edit your markup with the surrounding HTML.

Comment: show us the resultant div in a couple of different browsers. Or provide samples of the id's

Comment: This is ASP.Net. Rendered ClientID's don't match supplied ID's unless you put a `ClientIDMode="static"` on the element.

Comment: @Santi anyother solution besides static as i am using .net 3.5?

Comment: Sure. I've answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :visible selector inside is filtering function (jQuery):

```
if ($('#prftdiv').is(':visible'))
```

Comment: but my DIV id is Changing for different brosers

Comment: then use 
`if(($('#prftdiv').is(':visible')) || ($#div2').is('visible'))`

Answer (score 0):

instead of $('#ID') you can "select" a "route" to that element.
in you google dev tools, try to edit the element and remove its ID, after that right click the element and select COPY SELECTOR.

this should give you the best selector to that div, without using its ID.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could familiarize yourself with css attribute selectors.

```
$("div[id$='prftdiv']") //for ends with
$("div[id^='prftdiv']") //for starts with
$("div[id*='prftdiv']") //for contains
```

These are a couple of examples.

```
.is(":visible") //will get you the rest of your question.
```

[W3Schools for completeness](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

Comment: boss the id is changing when i am running in browser !!

Comment: i understand that, usually I believe that the ID of the element in question will end with the id you specified in your asp page.

Comment: in chrome it is cp_t100_prftdiv and in mozila it is cp_prftdiv_100,broswers rendering the client id !!

Comment: added contains selector sample

Comment: ok but lets say there are 5 div and all of them cantain the prftdiv then what ? thanks for the help though

Comment: Your only solution then is know the order of them and pick the correct index or use an ASP related solution as those provided.  Similar to @Santi answer.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `.is(':visible'))` is how you determine whether an element is visible. As for getting the ID, you should use `.attr('id')`, however you'd have to target the element through other means.

If you only have one such element with the `runat` attribute, perhaps do this to get the ID.

```
var div_id = $('div[runat="Server"]').attr('id');
```

But if the only reason to get the ID was to check its visibility then this is all you'd need.

```
if ($('div[runat="Server"]').is(':visible'))) {
  …
}
```

Comment: In ASP.Net, any server-side referenced element must have `runat="server"`, so while this might work, I'm not sure how likely that is.

Comment: @Santi I am unfamiliar with ASP.Net, so thank you for pointing that out. It was the only part I could draw from to make a potentially unique selector.

Answer (score 0):

What's unclear to me here is if you mean the ASP.Net server-side property `visible`, or simply client-side `visible`?

The difference between the two is that ASP.Net `visible="false"` controls *don't even render on the page*, therefore you need to check whether the element *exists* or not, rather than its visibility.

---

As far as the selector goes, you can fetch a `runat="server"` element's true ID by doing `myElement.ClientID`. Because this is server-side, you'll need to wrap it in `<%=`  `%>`

```
//Client-side visible
var isVisible = $("#<%= prftdiv.ClientId %>").is(":visible");
```

```
//Server-side visible
var isVisible = $("#<%= prftdiv.ClientId %>").length > 0;
```

```
//The logic, in either case
if (isVisible) console.log("Item is visible");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript then use :

```
document.getElementById("#<%=prftdiv.ClientID%>").style='display:block'
```

And better to use Jquery:

```
$("#<%=prftdiv.ClientID%>").show();
```

or

```
    $("#<%=prftdiv.ClientID%>").hide();
```